# Android : Floating Clickable Icon over Screen?

Tags: android, taskbar

There's an Android Application called `Smart Taskbar` that manages to Pin a small SemiTransparent Icon over the screen...The icon remains visible over **ALL** the activites (including the home screen). The Icon is Clickable (/Touchable), and it does popopen a Small Popup window which the user can interact with.

I'm very interested in how this is done? I think it's something to with `PopupWindow`.

Any ideas? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find an answer?

Comment: @shaimagz, i didn't have much luck, i moved on to other things but this thread might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android

Comment: Thanks but I saw this thread already. I think it something that we can find in the source code of Android. Because created the notification bar which appears all the time, and in any app unless your app wants to hide it. It should be something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently experimented with this.

See this question: [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android) - the solution is virtually the same, but you need to set `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` in the layout params instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

Comment: Interesting, will take a look at it...Leaving for home right now. :)

Comment: @Adam Woś, I'm trying the same concept in that question you linked. What I'm trying to figure out how I can get more than just a single touch event with a view layer that sits above all windows. Using TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY allows the user to fully interact with the touch screen but I can only pick up one touch event when the user first places their finger on. But with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, I can receive all the touch events but it locks interaction with everything else. Do you know how I "combine" both together to achieve something like what Wave Launcher and SwipePad can do? Sorry this a bit long!

Comment: Nope, sorry, haven't looked at this particular part of Android for a few months now :)